# The term "clause" in the context of programming

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

I've come across statements such as "the default clause" in the context of a switch statement or "the JOIN clause" in the context of SQL and I know what these statements mean but still I'd like to see a clear definition of the term.

Comment: It's impossible to define clause in language agnostic terms. Do you have a specific language?

Comment: @Rafe - I agree that you can't define what fragments constitute a clause in a particular language without referencing the language, but surely the concept is definable without reference to the language.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as in English (or another language).  A clause is an incomplete fragment of a sentence, or in this case a statement, that encapsulates an actor and an action.  In your example of a join clause, the action is the join and the actor is the table being joined.

Answer (score 9):

I think that there is a parallel *between a sentence and a dependent clause* in natural languages and *between a statement and a clause* in computer languages.

A clause does not stand by itself, but only makes sense within the context of a statement.

For example, the clauses

- "at 2:30" (adverbial clause)
- WHERE A.ID = B.ID (JOIN clause)

don't stand meaningfully on their own. However, those clauses make sense in the context of a sentence or statement.

- "Meet me at 2:30."
- SELECT A.NAME, B.ADDRESS FROM A, B WHERE A.ID = B.ID

A default clause in a switch statement of Java refers to the branch that is taken if none of the checked values match. The word "default" is somewhat problematic, as it usually means a failure of some sort (as in, "Your mortgage is in default"). With computer languages, it tends to mean "the unchosen choice."

It is a "clause" because it makes sense only in the context of other choices.

Comment: But can any part of a sentence (or a statement) be described with the term "clause"?

Comment: No, a clause is a unit of meaning. One theory of linguistics is called a Head-driven Phrase Structure Grammar (HPSG). It means that a phrase is not just a sequence of words, but words attached to a Head. For example, in the sentence "John hit the ball over the fence," the clause "over the fence" is a prepositional phrase in which the words hang together around the Head ("over"). There is no corresponding cohesion or meaning to "ball over" because they belong to different clauses. Similarly, in the Select statement above, "WHERE A.ID=B.ID" has meaning, but "B WHERE" does not.

Answer (score 2):

Like many terms in programming it simply means what it means in the [English language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause).

When I first saw `COALESCE` in SQL for example, I thought "What the hell?".  But you know what?  It does what it says on the tin:

> In phonetics and historical
>   linguistics, fusion, or coalescence,
>   is the merger of the features of two
>   segment into one.